# How could this be rewritten using ninject?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

What would the following example look like re-written to use Ninject?

Specifically how would you bind a Samurai to both Shuriken and Sword?

(From https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand)

```
interface IWeapon
{
    void Hit(string target);
}

class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(string target) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chopped {0} clean in half", target);
    }
}

class Shuriken : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(string target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pierced {0}'s armor", target);
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        var warrior1 = new Samurai(new Shuriken());
        var warrior2 = new Samurai(new Sword());
        warrior1.Attack("the evildoers");
        warrior2.Attack("the evildoers");    
       /* Output...
        * Piereced the evildoers armor.
        * Chopped the evildoers clean in half.
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Continue reading... https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject

Comment: Thats the point - I can't see in the examples how you bind to both Shuriken for warrior1 and sword for #2

Comment: You couldn't bind both implementations to `IWeapon` and resolve both independently, there's nothing telling the container to chose one over the other. Here are apparently "excruciatingly detailed" examples of how you can further describe what you need to resolve https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Comment: To me this question subverts the entire point of DI - you're asking for a specific _implemntation_, when the purpose of DI is to remove the dependency on an implementation.  You're saying "give me a sword" instead of saying "give me a weapon, I don't care what it is, ley the armory decide."  If you need a specific implemntation then DI is not adding anything.

Comment: I think you've missed the point that the SAMURAI is the one saying "Give me a weapon, any weapon" At some point *something* has to decide who's getting what! BTW The example is actually from the ninject site showing how to do DI without a IoC container - the Main sub is injecting the samurai with the weapon its depending on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply rebind `IWeapon` after resolving first `Samurai`:

```
StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>().Named();
Samurai samurai1 = kernel.Get<Samurai>();
samurai1.Attack("enemy");

kernel.Rebind<IWeapon>().To<Shuriken>();
Samurai samurai2 = kernel.Get<Samurai>();
samurai2.Attack("enemy");
```

Alternatively, you could use named bindings. It would be first necessary to redefine `Samurai`'s constructor a bit, adding a `Named` attribute to its dependency:

```
public Samurai([Named("Melee")]IWeapon weapon)
{
    this.weapon = weapon;
}
```

Then, you would need to give names to your bindings as well:

```
StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>().Named("Melee");
kernel.Bind<IWeapon>().To<Shuriken>().Named("Throwable");

Samurai samurai = kernel.Get<Samurai>();
samurai.Attack("enemy"); // will use Sword
```

There are really many alternatives - I would recommend browsing over the link provided by  @scottm and checking them all out.